# What do I do with $f(x+1)=f(x)$, seems to be a fourier question

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

It would seem having $f(x+1)=f(x)$ should just give me a straight line, since say $f(1)=2$,$f(2)=f(1)=2$ etc. So all $x$ are assigned to the one $y$ value, hence (here) I would have the line $y=2$.

What if I have another function with it? E.g I know that

$f(x) = x^2$

$f(x+1) = f(x)$

How do these interact? Do they only interact if I set them up for example:

$f(x) = x^2$, $-5\leq x\leq5$

$f(x+1) = f(x)$, $-\infty \lt x \lt \infty$

How does this look inside $[-5,5]$?

Comment: It means $f(x)$ is periodic in $x$ with period 1.  For example $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n \exp(2i\pi x)$

Comment: For any function defined on $[0,1]$ you can use $f(x+1)=f(x)$ to define it on the rest of $\mathbb{R}$. The equation just implies that $f$ is periodic with period $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f need not be a constant line at all, how about

> f(x) = sin(2 pi x)

Also, two definitions of f which are given contradict each other.  f(x+1) = f(x) is clearly periodic with period 1.  However, f(x) = x^2 is *not* periodic anywhere.  Did you mean two different functions, f & g?

Also, how do you know that $f(x) = x^2$?  This is valid for only a single point of $f(x) = f(x+1)$ namely x= 0 and x+1 = 1